# Java main class & sub classes - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Okay So I have a main class named `ScriptWorker` and a sub class named `Scriptworker$State`

However `ScriptWorker` is failing to recognize `Scriptworker$State`

Example,

```
if (Login.getLoginState().equals(Login.STATE.WELCOMESCREEN)) {
  return ScriptWorker.State.ON_WELCOME_SCREEN;
}

if (Login.getLoginState().equals(Login.STATE.INGAME)) {
  RSInterfaceMaster[] ints = Interfaces.getAll();
  for (RSInterfaceMaster i : ints) {
    if ((i.getChild(0).getUID() == 24313856) || (i.getUID() == 35913742)) {
      return ScriptWorker.State.TUTORIAL_ISLAND;
    }
  }
```

Error reads,

STATE IS WHERE THE ISSUE LIES

State cannot be resolved or is not a field.

**EDIT**

```
 enum State {
    ON_WELCOME_SCREEN("ON_WELCOME_SCREEN", 1),
    TUTORIAL_ISLAND("TUTORIAL_ISLAND", 8), 
    private State(final String s, final int n) { } 
 }
```

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: Done hopefully that helps, but the problem lies in STATE its self.. nothing else

Comment: Well i do think its against `Runescape's` terms of service to make a script/bot for it.. Also why do you have `**State**`

Comment: what is the Login class, what is the State class ? ..

Comment: Don't use markup in your code (remove the bolding `**`). SO handles all the proper coloring for code

Comment: First, `**` is invalid syntax; show us the actual code that you have. Second, this isn't enough code, we need to see the full context to see what's you have wrong.

Comment: State class is 

package scripts.BankChecker;

enum State
{
 
    ON_WELCOME_SCREEN("ON_WELCOME_SCREEN", 1), 
    TUTORIAL_ISLAND("TUTORIAL_ISLAND", 8), 
    
    private State(final String s, final int n) {
    }
}

Comment: @E-Riz I know what's wrong, I just don't know how to fix it, basically ScriptWorker$State.class isn't being imported into ScriptWorker, but I don't know how to resolve that

Comment: How did you get the .class files? Do you have source code for them?

Comment: @LucyBeale Does State is defined inside `ScriptWorker`? and is it define as static?

Comment: Need the ScriptWorker class, or at least the fields and constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @user902383 in the comments the enum needs to be static to be accessed like this:

```
Login.STATE
```

and unless this ifs are in the same package as the ScriptWorker it needs to be public either.

I hope it helped, if you could provide the ScriptWorker class (at least the parts that matter) I could be more precise.